# Excel Vba IE_automate: how to trigger changes on dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

Excel Vba IE_automate: how to trigger changes on dropdown list

Please visit the webpage
[www.twse.com.tw/zh/page/trading/fund/MI_QFIIS.html](http://www.twse.com.tw/zh/page/trading/fund/MI_QFIIS.html)
www.twse.com.tw/zh/page/trading/fund/MI_QFIIS.html

First dropdown list = year

Second dropdown list = month

Third dropdown list = day

If I manually change the value of second dropdown list, the month from 02 to 01,  the value of third dropdown list will automatically change to 01.  (first day of month)

however, if I use the follow codes.  the value of third dropdonw list wont change. 
I tried t.fireevent("onchange") but not working

```
Sub Getvaule()
   Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
   ie.Visible = True
   ie.navigate ("http://www.twse.com.tw/zh/page/trading/fund/MI_QFIIS.html") 
   While ie.readystate <> 4 Or ie.busy
   Wend

   For Each t In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("select")
     If Trim(t.Name) = "mm" Then
         t.Value = "1"                   
         While ie.readystate <> 4 Or ie.busy
         Wend
     End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Edited. sendkeys_example for reference

```
Sub sendkeys_example()
Dim ie, x

Set x = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Navigate "http://www.twse.com.tw/zh/page/trading/fund/MI_QFIIS.html"
ie.Visible = 1
ie.Toolbar = 0    
While ie.readystate <> 4 Or ie.Busy
Wend

x.SendKeys "{tab 4}", True
x.SendKeys "{down}"
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `SendKeys` to mimic what you are doing manually. In your example 3 Tabs bring you to the years combo, Enter opens the combo etc. This way you will have no problem

Comment: Thanks Siyon DP for giving me a direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using a browser at all and use xmlhttp request. You can pass the date as query string parameter then parse the json response with a jsonparser such as [jsonconverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas). After adding `jsonconverter.bas` to your project you need to go to `VBE > Tools > References > Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime`.

Just change the `date=20180104` to the required date and concatenate into the request url.

```
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim url As String, json As Object, headers(), fields As Object
    Dim data As Object, item As Object, results(), r As Long, c As Long

    url = "http://www.twse.com.tw/fund/MI_QFIIS?response=json&date=20180103&selectType=01&_=1550397583207"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
    End With

    Set fields = json("fields")
    Set data = json("data")

    ReDim headers(1 To fields.Count)
    ReDim results(1 To data.Count, 1 To fields.Count)

    For i = 1 To fields.Count
        headers(i) = fields(i)
    Next
    For Each item In data
        r = r + 1: c = 1
        For Each DataField In item
            results(r, c) = DataField
            c = c + 1
        Next
    Next
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers)) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Results:

[image]

Comment: if you are adding it as a variable yes. Dim as string and concantenate in. Dim dateField As String: dateField = "20180104" :  url = "http://www.twse.com.tw/fund/MI_QFIIS?response=json&date=" & dateField & "&selectType=01&_=1550397583207"

Comment: sorry to bother you again.  In situation like the following link https://histock.tw/stock/future.aspx  what shall I do to get the data?? @QHarr

Comment: looks like you can use xmlhttp and target the table tag. Have a go and if stuck post a question with your code and where stuck. If you put the link here I will have a look. https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/